# Line divides side of regular pentagon in Golden ratio

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, golden-ratio

[image]

In the figure, construct an equilateral triangle inside regular pentagon. The line connecting orthocenter and the [second Isodynamic point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondIsodynamicPoint.html) of green triangle divides the side of pentagon in red and blue segments.

> **My question.** How to prove that $$\frac{\rm{\color{red}{red}}}{\rm{ \color{blue}{blue}}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}?$$

Comment: I have verified this with a GeoGebra sketch, but an attempt at proof with, for instance, barycentric coordinates is exceedingly messy. Do you have a particular approach in mind? Perhaps you could say something about how you came across this property ... Is it a textbook exercise? an online challenge? something you observed while exploring aspects of the second isodynamic point? If there's a known solution out there, please say so (and explain that solution). This would help people avoid wasting time duplicating that effort.

Comment: Thank for your interest. I love the golden ratio in geometry so I often draw figures and try to observe it. Usually golden ratio appears in the regular pentagon so I often draw the pentagon first and combine it with some special diagrams. This time I chose an equilateral triangle and tried to observe. Perhaps I have drawn a lot of pictures and looked at them with my eyes, and finally I was lucky to see this result with Cabri II Plus.

You can see here similar problems

https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/GoldenRatioInPentagonAndTwoSquares.shtml

Comment: I've updated my answer with a companion construction. Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a *much* better argument than [my previous attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3256708/409). I'm leaving out a few details due to time constraints, but will update later.

---

Let pentagon $ABCDE$ have side-length $s$, and let $F$ be the apex of an equilateral triangle erected internally upon $\overline{CD}$. The orthocenter of $\triangle ABF$ is the intersection of $\overline{BE}$ with the perpendicular $\overline{FF'}$ from $F$ to $\overline{AB}$. Let $X$ be the point that separates $\overline{DE}$ in the golden ratio: $|DX|/|XE|=\phi$. Here's the key insight (proof left to the reader for now):

> The Second Isodynamic Point of $\triangle ABF$ is the apex ($Q$) of an equilateral triangle erected *externally* upon $\overline{DE}$.

[image]

We establish the result by showing the collinearity of $P$, $Q$, $X$ via [Menelaus' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) applied to $\triangle BEM$, where $M$ is the midpoint of $\overline{DE}$. A little angle chasing gives the various angle measures; we also use the facts $|BE|=s\phi$ and $\phi-1=\phi^{-1}$. Calculating the appropriate signed ratios ...

$$\begin{align}
\frac{|EX|}{|XM|}&=\phantom{-}\frac{s/(1+\phi)}{s/2-s/(1+\phi)}=\frac{2}{\phi-1} = 2\phi  \\[4pt]
\frac{|MQ|}{|QB|}&= -\frac{s\sin 60^\circ}{|EB|\sin\angle BEQ/\sin\angle BQE}= -\frac{s\sin 60^\circ}{s\phi\sin 132^\circ/\sin 30^\circ}= -\frac{s\sin 60^\circ}{2\phi\sin 48^\circ} \\[8pt]
\frac{|BP|}{|PE|} &= \phantom{-}\frac{|BF|\sin 48^\circ/\sin\angle FPB}{|EF|\sin 120^\circ/\sin\angle FPE} = \frac{\sin 48^\circ}{\sin 60^\circ}
\end{align}$$
... we see that their product is $-1$. Thus, Menelaus holds, and collinearity is verified. $\square$

**Note:** When $F$ is the apex of the triangle erected *externally* on $\overline{CD}$, then the *First* Isodynamic Point of $\triangle ABF$ is the apex of the triangle erected *internally* on $\overline{DE}$, and a similar argument holds to give the companion construction I described in [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3256708/409). The pentagram constructions follow similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thoroughly-unsatisfying approach that makes absolutely no attempt to exploit the specific geometry of the situation. It's just an algebraic slog.

---

First, we define $\theta := 6^\circ$, $c:=\cos\theta$, $s := \sin\theta$, noting that the minimal polynomial for $s$ is
$$\mu(s) = 1- 8s-16s^2+8s^3+16s^4 \tag{1}$$

Now, consider an origin-centered pentagon of circumradius $r$, with vertices $A$, $B$, $U$, $V$ as shown:

[image]

Point $C$ is the apex of the equilateral triangle erected upon the side opposite $A$. A little angle-chasing gives the various measures as multiples of $\theta$. Note that 
$$\frac{|OC|}{\sin\theta} = \frac{r}{\sin 5\theta} \quad\to\quad |OC| = 2 r \sin\theta = 2 r s \tag{2}$$
Abusing notation and writing $\operatorname{cis}\psi = (\cos\psi ,\sin\psi)$, we can coordinatize thusly:
$$A = r \operatorname{cis}0 \qquad B = r \operatorname{cis} 12\theta \qquad C = (2r s,0)$$

$$U= r\operatorname{cis}(-24\theta) \qquad V = r\operatorname{cis}(-12\theta) \tag{3}$$

With the help of a computer algebra system, we expand the various trig functions, re-write as much as possible in terms of $s=\sin\theta$, and reduce modulo $\mu(s)$ to get
$$\begin{align}
A &= r (1, 0) \\[4pt]
B &= r \left(\;s \left(3 - 4 s^2\right), c \left(1 - 4 s^2\right)\;\right) \\[4pt]
C &= r ( 2 s, 0 ) \\[8pt]
U &= r \left(\;\tfrac12\left(-1 - 6 s + 8 s^3\right), -c \left( 1 - 2 s\right) \left( 1 - 2 s - 4 s^2\right)\;\right) \\[4pt]
V &= r\left(\; s \left( 3 - 4 s^2 \right), -c \left( 1 - 4 s^2\right)\;\right)
\end{align}\tag{4}$$

Orthocenter $P$ has barycentric coordinates 
$$\alpha:\beta:\gamma \;=\;\sin A \cos B \cos C : \cos A \sin B \cos C : \cos A \cos B \sin C \tag{5}$$
so that, after the same kind of reduction as above, we get
$$P = \frac{\alpha A + \beta B + \gamma C}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma} = \left(\;
\frac{r ( 5 + 14 s - 4 s^2 - 16 s^3)}{
 2 (9 + 14 s - 8 s^2 - 16 s^3)}\;,\; 
\frac{ c r (1-2s)^2 (1+2s)}{9 + 14 s - 8 s^2 - 16 s^3}\;\right) \tag{6}$$

Second-Isodynamic Point $Q$ has barycentric coordinates
$$\alpha:\beta:\gamma = \sin A \sin(A-60^\circ) : \sin B \sin(B-60^\circ) : \sin C \sin(C-60^\circ) \tag{7}$$
so that
$$Q = \left(\;-\frac{r ( 11 + 8 s - 12 s^2 - 8 s^3)}{
  2 (9 + 14 s - 8 s^2 - 16 s^3)}\;,\; 
-\frac{2 c r (8 + 11 s - 8 s^2 - 12 s^3)}{ 9 + 14 s - 8 s^2 - 16 s^3}\;\right) \tag{8}$$
And, noting that we can write the Golden Ratio as $\phi = 2 \cos 6\theta$, and taking $W$ as the point that separates $\overline{UV}$ in that ratio, we have
$$W = \frac{U + \phi V}{1+\phi} = \left(\;
-\frac{r s (3 - 4 s^2)}{2 (1 - s) (1 + 2 s)^2}\;,\; 
-\frac{c r (1 - 2 s)^2 (3 + 4 s)}{2 (1 - s) (1 + 2 s)^2}
\;\right) \tag{9}$$

Now, we "simply" determine the equation of the line through $P$ and $Q$, which "reduces" to

$$\begin{align} 
2 c x &( 171 + 254 s - 180 s^2 - 264 s^3) \\
- \phantom{2x}y &( 163 + 254 s - 164 s^2 - 272 s^3) \\
= 2 c r &( 47 + 68 s - 48 s^2 - 72 s^3) 
\end{align}\tag{10}$$

Finally, we substitute $W$ into this equation, reduce modulo $\mu(s)$, and find that everything vanishes, verifying the claim. $\square$

---

While this approach offers no hint as to what magic lurks in the result, knowing that the proposition is true assures us that the quest for a magic-revealing proof is not inherently doomed.

---

**Addendum.** As one might expect, a few sign changes in the above analysis would work themselves out to validate a related result. Specifically, if we take $C$ to be apex of an equilateral triangle erected on the *outside* of the pentagon, and we take $Q$ to be the *first* isodynamic point of $\triangle ABC$, then the line through $Q$ and orthocenter $P$ meets $\overline{UV}$ in the same $W$, dividing the segment in the golden ratio.

[image]

I'll forego rewriting all the equations here, as I'm still seeking an appropriately-magical approach to understanding this construction. However, I'll give the following unifying notes:

$$C = r \left(\; -2 \sin(9\theta \mp 10\theta), 0\;\right) = r\left(\;-2\sin(9\theta\mp 60^\circ), 0\;\right)$$
$$\angle B = 12\theta \mp 5\theta = 12\theta\mp 30^\circ \qquad \angle C = 9\theta \pm 5 \theta = 9\theta\pm 30^\circ$$
$$Q \;\stackrel{\text{bary}}{=}\; \sin A \sin(A\mp 60^\circ):\cdots$$
where, in each "$\pm$" and "$\mp$", the top sign corresponds to OP's construction, and the bottom corresponds to mine. Seeing that the angles vary by multiples of $60^\circ$ is nicely compatible with the change in the isodynamic point's coordinates.

---

**Addendum 2.** What works for penta*gons* often works for penta*grams*, and that's the case here ... mostly. Curiously, the Second Isodynamic Point appears in both constructions; the First Isodynamic Point may also lead to another golden ratio somewhere, but I haven't looked very hard for it.

[image]

The figure shows a composite of two constructions with an equilateral triangle (apexes $C$ and $C'$) erected upon the edge of a pentagram (ie, a diagonal of the pentagon). Points $P$ (not shown) and $P'$ are the respective orthocenters, and $Q$ and $Q'$ the respective Second Isodynamic Points. Lines $\overleftrightarrow{PQ}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{P'Q'}$ concur with edge $\overleftrightarrow{UV}$ at $W$, such that $|VW|/|UW|=|UW|/|UV|=\phi$.

Interestingly, $\overleftrightarrow{UV}$ bisects $\angle QWQ'$, and $\overline{QW}\cong\overline{Q'W}$. This seems like it should be significant, but I don't know *how*.

For comparison, here's a composite image of the two pentagon constructions, showing the corresponding possibly-significant relations among $W$, $Q$, and $Q'$.

[image]

There's *something* going on here, but I just can't see it (yet).

Comment: Thank you for the interesting approach. Although it is algebra but it is very nice. You also show another construction golden ratio when the equilateral triangle erect out side pentagon.

Comment: @TranQuangHung: My approach isn't "interesting" ... it's *horrible*. :) It's completely devoid of insight. I don't think I've ever posted an argument I've disliked more. Be that as it may ... I've updated my answer with companion constructions on the pentagram. I'm increasingly hopeful that an actually-*good* argument can be made to justify them all.

Comment: @TranQuangHung: It occurs to me that I know your work! I reference one of your constructions (which I call "Tran's Square") in the ["Special Angles are Golden" entry](http://trigonography.com/2016/06/05/special-angles-are-golden/) of my Trigonography site. I'm currently restructuring that entry, and [another](http://trigonography.com/2016/06/22/special-angles-are-golden-ii/) along with two other families of results, into an article I plan to submit to *Forum Geometricorum*.

Comment: You have very interesting sites http://tricochet.com/, http://trigonography.com/ and http://daylateanddollarshort.com/bloog/category/hedronometry/. I hope I can discuss further with you by email.

I knew your work "Special Angles are Golden" two years ago. I have sent paper about Golden ratio to arxiv, https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.02011. I hope you will be interested in.